# Exposing headers on iPhone static library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, linker, static-libraries

I've followed [this](http://kyleroucis.com/Kyle_Roucis/Blog/Entries/2009/10/7_Custom_Embedded_Static_Library_for_iPhone.html) tutorial for setting up a static library with common classes from 3 projects we are working on.

It's pretty simple, create a new static library project on xcode, add the code there, a change some headers role from `project` to `public`. The tutorial says I should add my library folder to the `header search paths` recursively.

Is this the right way to go?

I mean, on my library project, I have files separated in folders like `Global/`, `InfoScreen/`, `Additions/`. I was trying to setup one `LOKit.h` file on the root folder, and inside that file #import everything I need to expose. So on my host project I don't need to add the folder recursively to the header search path, and would just `#import "LOKit.h"`.

But I couldn't get this to work, the host project won't build complaining about all the classes I didn't add to `LOKit.h`, even though the library project builds.

So, my question is, what is the *right* way of exposing header files when I setup a Cocoa Touch Static Library project on xCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting up a `LOKit.h` on the project root folder like this:

```
#import "Global/LOCommon.h"
#import "Additions/LOAdditions.h"
#import "View/LOCustomView1.h"
#import "View/LOCustomView2.h"
```

And on my host project I set the header search path variable to my library's root folder, without recursion. Whenever I need to, I just import `LOKit.h`.

I also included on this library project common libraries (like JSON, FBConnect and Reachabillity) that were shared across projects. This way I only need to update those libraries in one place, once.

Answer (score 0):

When using static libraries I usually go one of the following two ways:

If I created the library myself and it is somewhat tightly coupled to the project which uses the lib, I usually create a source root for the library in the XCode settings. Then you can add the source root as a variable to the header paths recursively.

On the other hand, if the library is either not by me, or is maintained entirely separately from my project, I usually copy a version of the library plus the relevant headers to the project using it and reference those. This is a bit more cumbersome if you need constant updates, but does not break your application if something in the library changes.

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion was pretty much what I was already doing. But I really wanted to avoid adding the folder to the header search paths recursive, so I can choose what to expose and what would just confuse the library user.